# How do I position the cursor to stack the circles in the picture?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to recreate this photo, colors and all. I'm having trouble with positioning the turtle to stack the circles.

I've already tried `setheading()` and `setposition()`.

Code I've tried:

```
turtle.circle(50)
turtle.setheading(270)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two of the commands you need to draw the circles.  The other commands you need are `fillcolor()`, `begin_fill()` and its companion `end_fill()`:

```
import turtle

turtle.setheading(0)
turtle.fillcolor('blue')
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(50)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.setheading(90)
turtle.fillcolor('green')
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(50)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.setheading(180)
turtle.fillcolor('yellow')
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(50)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.setheading(270)
turtle.fillcolor('cyan')
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(50)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.done()
```

We can do better using a Python loop:

```
import turtle

for quadrant, color in enumerate(['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'cyan']):
    turtle.setheading(90 * quadrant)
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(50)
    turtle.end_fill()

turtle.done()
```

If you want to challenge yourself, use what you learn solving the above problem, and read about the `extent` argument to `turtle.circle()`, to draw this variation:

[image]

You will likely also need to use `left()` and/or `right()` to draw it, as well as learn how the sign of the radius affects `turtle.circle()`.